# MassTransit, with RabbitMq, didn't retry when occured error

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, queue, masstransit

I've got a problem with the Retries on MassTransit, with rabbitmq.

I have got the code configuration:

```
        private static void ConfigureMassTransitWithRabbitMq(this IServiceCollection services, string host, string username, string pwd, string cluster, Assembly assembly)
        {   
            services.AddMassTransit(config =>
            {
                config.AddConsumers(assembly);

                config.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

                config.UsingRabbitMq((context, rabbitMqConfig) =>
                {   
                    rabbitMqConfig.UseRetry(e => Retry.Immediate(3));
                    rabbitMqConfig.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                    rabbitMqConfig.ConfigurePublish(pipe => 
                    { 
                        pipe.UseExecute(context1 => 
                        { 
                            if (context1.CorrelationId == null) 
                            { 
                                context1.CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(); 
                            } 
                        }); 
                    });

                    rabbitMqConfig.Host(new Uri(host), hst =>
                    {
                        hst.Username(username);
                        hst.Password(pwd);
                        hst.PublisherConfirmation = true;
                        hst.Heartbeat(5);
                        hst.UseCluster(c =>
                        {
                            var clusters = cluster?.Split(';');

                            if (cluster == null || clusters.Length == 0)
                                return;

                            foreach (var item in clusters)
                                c.Node(item);
                        });
                    });

                    rabbitMqConfig.ManagementEndpoint((conf) =>
                    {
                        conf.ConfigurePublish((p) =>
                        {
                            p.UseRetry((r) =>
                            {
                                r.Exponential(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
        }
```

I add my consumers by assembly.

I just try to use:

- `rabbitMqConfig.UseRetry(e => Retry.Immediate(3));` When I configure the MassTransit

But in this case, de configuration stay an infinite loop

---

And I try to use this:

```
        try
        {
            var order = _mapper.Map<object>(context.Message);
            await Execute(order);
            await context.ConsumeCompleted;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            var retry = context.GetRetryCount();
           
            if (maxAttempts > 3)
            {
                throw;
            }

            await context.Redeliver(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
```

And I put this code in MassTransitConfiguration:

```
rabbitMqConfig.UseDelayedExchangeMessageScheduler();
```

---

In the last case, I got the retry, but I never got the amount of retry, so I don't get to control it. I try to get this amount by header and other properties too, but I always got 0.

Can anyone help me?!

Comment: I'd put `ConfigureEndpoints` _last_ in your configuration, and the `Host` first. The pipeline is ordered, so be sure to add your filters, etc. in order. Retry is in-memory, you shouldn't be calling redeliver nor trying to retry on your own. There are examples of everything you're trying to do in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChrisPatterson! And could you send me the documentation link that shows this specific case (similar to adding consumers by the assembly and configure all in a generic way)?

Answer (score 2):

The order of your configuration is wrong, the corrected configuration based upon your example above is shown below:

```
private static void ConfigureMassTransitWithRabbitMq(this IServiceCollection services, string host, string username, string pwd, string cluster, Assembly assembly)
{   
    services.AddMassTransit(config =>
    {
        config.AddConsumers(assembly);

        config.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

        config.UsingRabbitMq((context, rabbitMqConfig) =>
        {   
            rabbitMqConfig.Host(new Uri(host), hst =>
            {
                hst.Username(username);
                hst.Password(pwd);
                hst.Heartbeat(5);
                hst.UseCluster(c =>
                {
                    var clusters = cluster?.Split(';');

                    if (cluster == null || clusters.Length == 0)
                        return;

                    foreach (var item in clusters)
                        c.Node(item);
                });
            });

            rabbitMqConfig.ConfigurePublish(pipe => 
            { 
                pipe.UseExecute(context1 => 
                { 
                    context1.CorrelationId ??= Guid.NewGuid(); 
                }); 
            });

            rabbitMqConfig.UseRetry(e => Retry.Immediate(3));

            rabbitMqConfig.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });
    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
}
```

> I also removed anything that wasn't required, either because it was default behavior, or unused.

Comment: Late to the game... But this is an awesome answer! OP should mark it as approved.